# Turn third cell red if preceding 2 cells = <1 for any consecutive 2 cells in all rows (12 rows in total) meeting this criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I am hoping to put together an attendance sheet which highlights a third or fourth cell in a row (12 cells for a 12 week semester) where the preceding 2 cells have values less than 2.

Basically what I want to achieve is a kind of 'red flag' or alert for a student who has been absent for any three consecutive days throughout the entire semester.

Alternatively, a cell in an end column with a note such as "refer to academic support" when these criteria are met could be a good alternative.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting to do that.

First, select the range to apply conditional formatting:
[image]
Note D2:M6 is selected, with D2 being the active cell.

Next, select Conditional formatting > New Rule and input the formula as below:
[image]

Note the formula `=AND(B2<2, C2<2)` is with reference to D2 (i.e. the active cell).  Click on the "Format..." button and set whatever format you wish.

The condition will apply to the whole area of D2:M6.  If you wish to avoid turning columns F to M into red (as previous columns are blank and therefore <2) you can amend the formula as `=AND(B2<2, C2<2, NOT(ISBLANK(B2)), NOT(ISBLANK(C2)))`.

Comment: It appears that multiple cells are turning red when I use the NOT(ISBLANK(B2)) functions. Unfortunately, the cells (i.e. D2) are coming up red even if the preceding cells are more than or equal to 2. Is there something I could add to the above formula to change this. Instead of '<2' should it be something like: 'B2 + C2 + D2<2'

Comment: When preceding cells (say B2) is more than or equal to 2 (as in my example), obviously `B2<2` is false and the condition `=AND(B2<2, C2<2, NOT(ISBLANK(B2)), NOT(ISBLANK(C2)))` become false.  Conditional formatting therefore won't turn it red, at least on my computer.  So... can you please elaborate with some sample data?

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback. Yes, following your formula here, cells are still turning red even when the sum of the preceding 2 cells = 2. Also, after the third cell, all remaining cells light up red as well. My formula is: =AND(E8<2, F8<2, NOT(ISBLANK(E8)), NOT(ISBLANK(F8)))

Comment: Oops so you meant **sum of preceding 2 cells**, not both of the two cells.  What's the values in E8 and F8?

Comment: Oh, my error there - i should have been clearer. Yes, I think in this case it would be the sum of any preceding 3 consecutive cells =<2. Is this at all possible? The values of each cell are 0, 0.5 or 1. Therefore, the sum of any 3 preceding consecutive cells should be <2 to meet the rule which turns the 4th cell in any area of the range red. I hope I am making more sense. Thank you.

Comment: Then you can apply the condition accordingly like you have suggested like `B2 + C2 + D2<2` when cell E2 is the active cell.